# Angular compile complete event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a html template that's been compiled and added to my dom via an append function. However it is not possible to change the style of the template objects because I have to wait till they are completely rendered in the dom. How is this possible?

My method call looks like that at the moment:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('htmlContent')).append(app.compile(template)(app.rootScope));
```

Comment: **1.** For styles, add class in the template and define its styles in CSS **2.** For complete callback wrap your code in setTimeout with 0 duration, `setTimeout(function() { ...... }, 0);`

Comment: setTimeout works great - thx a lot for that tip.